# No puedo importar el .jar ksoap2 en Android Studio

Tags: android, ksoap

Tengo un proyecto Android en el cual quiero usar el .jar ksoap2.

En Android Studio pegue el archivo .jar en la carpeta libs de mi proyecto, después sobre dicho archivo di clic derecho y "Add as Library".

Posteriormente sincronice mi gradle, lo cual dio como resultado que Android Studio actualizara el archivo build.gradle de la siguiente forma:

```
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.1.jar')
```

Finalmente en mi clase MainActivity.java intento escribir import org.ksoap2.Envelope pero el IDE no reconoce la clase y la desaparece, no me es posible importar la clase.

¿Estoy cometiendo algún error en el procedimiento?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para aprovechar las ventajas de gradle, te recomiendo probar de esta manera:

Importar la libreria mediante Gradle:

```
repositories {
     maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
}
dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.1'
}
```

Podrás eliminar el .jar de la carpeta libs

Comment: Israel muchas gracias por tu respuesta, al tratar de hacer el import en mi clase, al comenzar a escribir el import ya observo que Android Studio reconoce la clase org.ksoap2.SoapEnvolve. Pero cuando termino de escribirla el IDE la desaparece automáticamente. ¿A qué puede deberse esto? Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: ¿Desaparece el texto escrito, o de las sugerencias que da el IDE? Creo que estas confundiendo con las "sugerencias" que da el IDE mientras escribes, pero completado el texto o escribir algo mal, la sugerencia desaparece. Podría aparecer en un tono gris, si no usas ninguna clase, metodo o funcion de dicho paquete, o rojo en caso de error, pero hasta donde yo se, no desaparecen.

Comment: Muchas gracias por seguir comentando sobre mi pregunta, en el IDE me pasa lo siguiente. En la zona de imports, tecleo "import import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;", terminado de escribir el IDE lo desaparece, considero que lo hace así debido a que en ningún objeto de dicha clase. Lo que hice fue escribir SoapObject miObjetoSoap = new SoapObject(namespace,metros); y el IDE reconoció automáticamente el import, pero si yo quiero agregarlo manualmente, lo elimina después de terminar de teclear el import.

Comment: Se quedara en gris, pero no se puede borrar, no obstante la manera que has echo es la mas cómoda, escribe algo de ese paquete y que el mismo ide se encargue de los import